# Is there a better way to find set intersection for Search engine code?

Tags: algorithm, set, search-engine, intersection, information-retrieval

I have been coding up a small search engine and need to find out if there is a faster way to find set intersections. Currently, I am using a Sorted linked list as explained in most search engine algorithms. i.e for every word I have a list of documents sorted in a list and then find the intersection among the lists.

The performance profiling of the case is [here](http://harisankar-krishnaswamy.blogspot.in/2012/02/how-to-code-your-own-search-engine-like.html).
Any other ideas for a faster set intersection?

Comment: You could start with a binary search, avoiding the linear stepping at the begin. (this can be extended to the overlapping part, by some 'hunting' method) BTW: linked list are not the best representation for large sorted sets. You could try arrays.

Comment: the binary search is a good idea. It will defenitely help skipping if introduced. then array Vs List would it really matter if the list / array is changed only during only updating the search datastructures? many thanks

Answer (score 2):

An efficient way to do it is by "zig-zag":

Assume your terms is a list `T`:

```
lastDoc <- 0 //the first doc in the collection
currTerm <- 0 //the first term in T
while (lastDoc != infinity):
  if (currTerm > T.last): //if we have passed the last term:
     insert lastDoc into result
     currTerm <- 0
     lastDoc <- lastDoc + 1
     continue
  docId <- T[currTerm].getFirstAfter(lastDoc-1)
  if (docID != lastDoc):
     lastDoc <- docID
     currTerm <- 0
  else: 
     currTerm <- currTerm + 1
```

This algorithm assumes efficient `getFirstAfter()` which can give you the first document which fits the term and his docId is greater then the specified parameter. It should return infinity if there is none.

The algorithm will be most efficient if the terms are sorted such that the rarest term is first.

The algorithm ensures at most `#docs_matching_first_term * #terms` iterations, but practically - it will usually be much less iterations.

More info can be found in [this lecture notes](http://webcourse.cs.technion.ac.il/236621/Winter2011-2012/ho/WCFiles/lec4-evaluation.pdf) slides 11-13 [copy rights in the lecture's first page]

Comment: will give this a try and see how it fares. thanx

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [research paper](http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~ajsaling/papers/paper-spire.pdf) that has a quantitave analysis for comparing current algorithms.