# Looking for a faster algorithm to count tags/keywords/labels on a document database for a dynamic tagcloud

Tags: c#, .net, sql, algorithm, tag-cloud

**Current state**

- .NET 4.0 Application (WPF)
- Database: SQLCE
- Tables (simplified): Documents, Tags, DocumentsTags [n:n]
- roughly 2000 documents and 600 tags (tags can be assigned to multiple documents)
- tags = keywords = labels

**Case**

The user has a big document database, which he can filter with a tag cloud. The tags displays a name (the tag name itself) and a number, which is the total count of the documents with the respective tag.
If the user selects a tag, only the documents with the selected tag are shown. The dynamic tag cloud now should show only the available tags on the filtered documents with an updated count number.

**Problem**

It is slow. After each selected tag, we need to evaluate again all the documents to count the tags. We currently do it recursively, so we check on each document what tags it has. We are looking for another solution (caching, better algorithm, your idea?).

**Similarities**

stackoverflow, del.icio.us also have tag clouds. Check out yourself. How do they do it? I know stored procedures would be a solution, but according our database developer this is not available on SQLCE.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that the slow part is displaying the tags **just for the list of documents selected by one tag** ?

Comment: Well actually the less documents are displayed, the faster it goes, as we do get the tags each time when the list is filtered. Now at the start of the application all 2000 documents are available and our application gets all the tags document by document.

Comment: My answer below helps with that! No need to cycle the documents, you can do this in one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two [inverted indexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index), where each tag will be a key in both.

One inverted index will actually be a `map:Tags->list of Tags` [all the tags that co-occure with the key]

The second one will be `map:Tags->list of Docs` [all the documents that co-occure with each tag].

Calculating the relevant set of docs after some tags were selected is simply an intersection on inverted index, that can be done efficiently.

Also, finding the modified tags cloud is again an intersection on inverted index.

Note that the inverted index can be created off-line, and creating it is a classic example of [map-reduce](http://research.google.com/archive/mapreduce.html) usage.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209693/is-there-a-better-way-to-find-set-intersection-for-search-engine-code) discuss how to efficiently find intersection in inverted index

Comment: This seems to be very promising. We have to look into this solution, which will take some time. Thanks for your contribution!

Answer (score 0):

You should do your **second stage** search in a single query, something like

```
SELECT
  tags.id AS tagid,
  tags.name AS tagname,
  count(*) AS tagcount
FROM
  tags
  INNER JOIN DocumentsTags AS tda on tda.tagid=tags.id
  INNER JOIN DocumentsTags AS tdb on tda.documentid=tdb.documentid
WHERE
  tdb.tagid=<selected tag id>
GROUP BY
  tags.id
```

**Edit**

After your comment, this is what you should use for the **first stage** query (i.e.: No tag yet selected, all documents in list)

```
SELECT
  tags.id AS tagid,
  tags.name AS tagname,
  count(*) AS tagcount
FROM
  tags
  INNER JOIN DocumentsTags AS tda on tda.tagid=tags.id
GROUP BY
  tags.id
```